# Bootstrap button sizes not working?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here are three different button sizes:

```html
<div class="btn-group btn-small">
    <button class="btn btn-small btn-success" href="#" type="button">Approve</button>
    <button class="btn btn-small btn-danger" href="#" type="button">Deny</button>
</div>

<div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn btn-mini btn-success" href="#">Approve</a>
    <a class="btn btn-mini btn-danger" href="#">Deny</a>
</div>

<div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn btn-success" href="#">Approve</a>
    <a class="btn btn-danger" href="#">Deny</a>
</div>
```

All three of those result in this:

[image: screenshot]

Why would `btn`, `btn-success`, `btn-danger` and `btn-group` all work, but not btn-mini/small/etc?

Comment: What version of Bootstrap are you using?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Bootstrap changed the names of their buttons from 2.x ➡ to 3.x

#### Version Comparison

```
|    2.x     |   3.x   |   4.x   |
|------------|---------|---------|
| .btn-large | .btn-lg | .btn-lg |
| .btn-small | .btn-sm | .btn-sm |
| .btn-mini  | .btn-xs |    -    |
```

#### Demo for Bootstrap 3

So your updated code should look like this:

```html
<div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn btn-xs btn-success" href="#">Approve</a>
    <a class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" href="#">Deny</a>
</div>
<br>
<div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-success" href="#">Approve</a>
    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="#">Deny</a>
</div>
<br>
<div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn btn-success" href="#">Approve</a>
    <a class="btn btn-danger" href="#">Deny</a>
</div>
```

[Demo in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/Zv4ha/) which will produce this:

[image: screenshot]

#### Docs from various versions

- [Bootstrap Buttons 2.x](https://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#buttons)
- [Bootstrap Buttons 3.x](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#buttons)
- [Bootstrap Buttons 4.x](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#buttons)
- [Migration Guide 2 ➡ 3](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/migration/)
- [Migration Guide 3 ➡ 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#buttons)

Comment: Crap, so I have google to thank for leading me to http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#buttons I guess :(

Comment: Yep, historically that's been a popular link for people who have searched for bootstrap; now not so much.

Comment: that explains some things!

Answer (score 16):

(If someone came here wondering why `btn-xs` or `btn-group-xs` is not working in >= 4.0)

Change log from bootstrap 3.0 to 4.0:

> Dropped the .btn-xs class entirely as .btn-sm is proportionally much
> smaller than v3’s.
>
> ...
>
> Dropped the .btn-group-xs class entirely given removal of .btn-xs.

[Source](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/)

Answer (score 5):

You have to change the classes if you use the [version 3.0](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons-sizes)

http://jsfiddle.net/WrQNh/1/

```
<div class="btn-group btn-small">
    <button class="btn btn-xs btn-success" href="#" type="button">Approve</button>
    <button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" href="#" type="button">Deny</button>
</div>
<br>
<div class="btn-group"> <a class="btn btn-sm btn-success" href="#">Approve</a>
     <a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="#">Deny</a>
</div>
<br>
<div class="btn-group"> <a class="btn btn-success" href="#">Approve</a>
    <a class="btn btn-danger" href="#">Deny</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I am using bootstrap 3.3.7 and wanted to use btn-xs, as extra small than btn-sm? used custom css but text-inside btn has more height and extra padding which can't be nullified? how can I use btn-xs?

Answer (score 3):

Also make sure that if bootstrap.css is being overridden by our own customised *.css file, then you have .btn-sm.... logic added into your customised *.css file. This was the problem in my case as it turned out.

Comment: Why the down vote here!? It's a reasonable point which has also happened to me when using bootstrap with Django several times.

Comment: This is odd.  Can't figure out why customizing other btn classes kills the btn-xs (in my case) or btn-sm styles as was the problem in your case.